# Move to view controller without clicking on Tab Bar Item representing it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `TabBarController` having 3 viewcontrollers in it (namely VCa, VCb, VCc) and at VCa the tabbar is set as hidden.
Now whenever we tap(using `UITapGestureRecognizer`) the view at VCa, what should be the selector method to be implemented in order to view another ViewController (either VCb or VCc).

"At `viewdidLoad` of VCa"

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapmethod)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

-(void)tap{
// code to be written in order to show VCb(or any other ViewController in same TabBarController)
}
```

Comment: Please, read the docs : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained in the docs : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController

In short :

```
- (void)tap {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
    // or
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
}
```

The correct tab bar item will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Set the selectedIndex of UITabBarViewController to the VC that you want to show.

Comment: You should handle it in 
-(void)tap{
// code to be written in order to show VCb(or any other ViewController in same TabBarController)
}